# Using a variable in the later part of the program (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect two separate codes into one program. I need to put one string from first to second part.

First:

```
import boto3

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bucket='BUCKET-NAME'
    collectionId='COLLECTION-ID'
    fileName='input.jpg'
    threshold = 70
    maxFaces=1

    client=boto3.client('rekognition')


    response=client.search_faces_by_image(CollectionId=collectionId,
                                Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':fileName}},
                                FaceMatchThreshold=threshold,
                                MaxFaces=maxFaces)


    faceMatches=response['FaceMatches']
    for match in faceMatches:
            print (match['Face']['FaceId'])
```

Second:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('faces')

response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('faceid').eq('FaceId')
)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

I need to put ID shown by `print (match['Face']['FaceId'])` from first code to `FaceId` in second code.

I tried to define a variable and put a value into it and then get it later but I could not do it correctly

Comment: Maybe, write the variable to a text file, and read it from the other code? P.S I have no idea how code on AWS is executed. **If** they are executed in **parallel**, then my next best guess would be to create an async call from the first script to the other.

Comment: Are these two separate programs, or simply separate sections of the same file? What is triggering each code block? I ask because the calling method could be used to pass information between the blocks.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: This is two separate sections of the same file.

Comment: If they are both in the same file, how does the second code block get called? You should either pass information between functions, or use a **global variable** to store something you need to access from multiple portions of code.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you're write your first block of code as a library/module with a function that does some unit of work and `returns` the result. Then the second block of code would `import` the first and call the function.

```
# lib.py
def SomeFunction(inputs):
  output = doSomething(inputs)
  return output

# main.py
import lib
data = ...
result = lib.SomeFunction(data)
moreWork(result)
```

If you want two separate programs that run independently and share data, you want [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). You can get processes to share information with each other via: a file/fifo in the filesystem; a network socket; shared memory; and STDIO (and probably more). However, IPC is definitely more work than synchronous library calls.